# How to Skip frames while decoding H264 stream?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, decode, h.264

I'm using FFMPEG to decode H264 (or H265) RTSP Stream.

My system have 2 software: Server and Client

```
Server: Read frames from RTSP stream --> Forward frames to Client    
Client: Receive frames from Server --> Decode --> Render
```

I have implemented and it worked ok, but there is a case make my system work not good. That is when internet from Server - Client is slow, frames can not transfer real-time to Client.

In present, I deal with this issue by Skip some frames (not send to Client) when the Queue is reached limit of count. The following is my summary code

```
//At Server Software (include 2 threads A and B)
//Thread A: Read AVPacket and forward to Client
while(true)
{
    AVPacket packet;
    av_init_packet(&packet);
    packet.size = 0;
    packet.data = NULL;
    int ret = AVERROR(EAGAIN);
    while (AVERROR(EAGAIN) == ret)
        ret = av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet);
    if(packet.size > 0)
    {
        if(mySendQueue.count < 120) //limit 120 packet in queue
            mySendQueue.Enqueue(packet); ////Thread B will read from this queue, to send packets to Client via TCP socket
        else
            ;//SkipThisFrame ***: No send
    }
}
//Thread B: Send To Client via TCP Socket
While(true)
{
    AVPacket packet;
    if(mySendQueue.Dequeue(packet))
    {
        SendPacketToClient(packet);
    }
}

//At Server Software : Receive AVPacket from Server --> Decode --> Render
While(true)
{
    AVPacket packet;
    AVFrame frame;
    ReadPacketFromServer(packet);
    if (av_decode_asyn(pCodecCtx, &frame, &frameFinished, &packet) == RS_OK)
    {
        if (frameFinished)
        {
            RenderFrame(frame);
        }
    }           
}
UINT32 __clrcall av_decode_asyn(AVCodecContext *pCodecCtx, AVFrame *frame, int *frameFinished, AVPacket *packet)
{
    int ret = -1;
    *frameFinished = 0;
    if (packet) 
    {
        ret = avcodec_send_packet(pCodecCtx, packet);
        // In particular, we don't expect AVERROR(EAGAIN), because we read all
        // decoded frames with avcodec_receive_frame() until done.
        if (ret < 0 && ret != AVERROR_EOF)
            return RS_NOT_OK;
    }

    ret = avcodec_receive_frame(pCodecCtx, frame);
    if (ret < 0 && ret != AVERROR(EAGAIN))
    {
        return RS_NOT_OK;
    }
    if (ret >= 0)
        *frameFinished = 1;

    return RS_OK;
}
```

My question is focus in line of code `SkipThisFrame ***`, this algorithm skip frame continuously, so it maybe make the decoder on Client occur unexpectedly error or Crash?

And when skip frame like that, make Client Render frames is not normally?

And someone call show me the proper algorithm to skip frames in my case?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Shouldn't that logic be `Server: Store "incoming" frames from RTSP stream --> Forward "existing" frames to Client`?

Comment: @VC.One: Thank you! I understand that you said, but when internet is slow, I have to skip frames for real-time render on Client. I consider that which algorithm of skip frame is best

Comment: As other already have stated, you cannot skip decoding frames in a h264 stream since a P-frame (predicted) just contains the differences towards the last reconstructed one. However, what you can do is to skip showing frames on the display in question and limit the perceived fps.

Answer (score 2):

I have a brief read on doc of `AVPacket`, it says:

> For video, it should typically contain one compressed frame.

Theoretically you cannot skip frames for a compressed video stream, as most frames do not contain complete information about that frame's image, but only contain changes compared with some previous frames. So if you skip a frame, it is probable that many trailing decoded frames won't contain correct result (until next key frame flushes whole image).

Comment: Thank you! I understand that you said, but when internet is slow, I have to skip frames for real-time render on Client. I consider that which algorithm of skip frame is best

Answer (score 1):

> *"My question is focus in line of code `SkipThisFrame ***`, this algorithm
>   **skip frame continuously**, so it maybe make the decoder on Client occur
>   unexpectedly error or Crash?"*

One thing I notice is wrong... 
Your `While(true)` statements also need a `break;` to stop, otherwise they will run forever, blocking other functions and causing the system to crash. Think about it, you say *"While the loop is true do X-Y-Z instructions"* but you never say when to stop (*eg:* `break` out of this While loop to do next instructions). Computer is stuck doing first `While` loop only and also repeating that to infinity...

Try setting up like this:

```
//At Server Software (include 2 threads A and B)
//Thread A: Read AVPacket and forward to Client
while(true)
{
    AVPacket packet;
    av_init_packet(&packet);
    packet.size = 0;
    packet.data = NULL;
    int ret = AVERROR(EAGAIN);

    while (AVERROR(EAGAIN) == ret) { ret = av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet); }

    if(packet.size > 0)
    {
        if(mySendQueue.count < 120) //limit 120 packet in queue
        {
            mySendQueue.Enqueue(packet); ////Thread B will read from this queue, to send packets to Client via TCP socket
        }
        //else {  } //no need for ELSE if doing nothing... //SkipThisFrame ***: No send
    }

    break; //stop this part and move to "Thead B"
}

//Thread B: Send To Client via TCP Socket
While(true)
{
    AVPacket packet;
    if( mySendQueue.Dequeue(packet) )
    { SendPacketToClient(packet); break; }
}

//At Server Software : Receive AVPacket from Server --> Decode --> Render
While(true)
{
    AVPacket packet; AVFrame frame;
    ReadPacketFromServer(packet);
    if (av_decode_asyn(pCodecCtx, &frame, &frameFinished, &packet) == RS_OK)
    { 
        if (frameFinished) { RenderFrame(frame);  break; }
    }           
}

UINT32 __clrcall av_decode_asyn(AVCodecContext *pCodecCtx, AVFrame *frame, int *frameFinished, AVPacket *packet)
{
    int ret = -1;
    *frameFinished = 0;
    if (packet) 
    {
        ret = avcodec_send_packet(pCodecCtx, packet);
        // In particular, we don't expect AVERROR(EAGAIN), because we read all
        // decoded frames with avcodec_receive_frame() until done.
        if (ret < 0 && ret != AVERROR_EOF)
            return RS_NOT_OK;
    }

    ret = avcodec_receive_frame(pCodecCtx, frame);
    if (ret < 0 && ret != AVERROR(EAGAIN))
    {
        return RS_NOT_OK;
    }
    if (ret >= 0)
        *frameFinished = 1;

    return RS_OK;
}
```

Hope it helps. Let me know of results / errors.

Comment: One: Don't worry about this, this is only a summary code for everyone can read easily, not full code, these are basic and I know to control them. I want to focus on the my question. Thank you so much!